# parsing with nokogiri into a table where there are multiple labels in each cell of a certain column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, nokogiri

Im trying to parse labels out of a table with nokogiri, where there are more than one in only one td field:

```
    <tr class="alt2">
      <td class="company">ABB Shanghai Transformer Co., Ltd.</td>
      <td class="contactperson">Mr.  Frank Liang<br/></td>
      <td class="businesscategory">
        <label><code>C27.11 </code>Manufacture of electric motors, generators and transformers</label>
        <label><code>C27.33 </code>Manufacture of wiring devices</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

So what I've done now is this:

```
 doc.css("tbody tr").each do |company|
   new = GermanSubsidiary.new
   new.name = company.at_css(".company").text
   new.contact = company.at_css(".contactperson").text 
   company.at_css(".businesscategory label").each do |category|
     new_class = BusinessClassification.create
     new_class.code = category.at_css("code").text
     new_class.name = category.text
   end
 end
```

unfortunately `company.at_css(".businesscategory label").each do |category|` is not working because at_css doesn't work for arrays... is it?

How can I parse deeper into the structure? As there is a table with multiple lines I have to distinguish in witch line I aim, and can't use the xpath command over the whole document.

Thanks Markus

Comment: the solution is: company.at_css(".businesscategory").children

Comment: `company` is not an array, it is a `<tr>` element. What do you mean when you say that it is "not working"? In the future, please provide not just your sample input and code (which is great), but also the sample output you are trying to get as well as the actual error messages or incorrect output you are getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.at_css('.businesscategory label')` only returns the first matching node. Use `.css('.businesscategory label')` to get all the matching nodes

this xml

```
xml = <<-XML
<tbody>
  <tr class="alt2">
    <td class="company">ABB Shanghai Transformer Co., Ltd.</td>
    <td class="contactperson">Mr.  Frank Liang<br/></td>
    <td class="businesscategory">
      <label><code>C27.11 </code>Manufacture of electric motors, generators and transformers</label>
      <label><code>C27.33 </code>Manufacture of wiring devices</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
XML
```

and this script

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(xml)

puts "with at_css example:"
doc.css("tbody tr").each do |company|
  company.at_css(".businesscategory label").each do |category|
    puts category.at_css("code").text
    puts category.text
  end
end

puts "\n\nwith css"
doc.css("tbody tr").each do |company|
  company.css(".businesscategory label").each do |category|
    puts category.at_css("code").text
    puts category.text
  end
end
```

prints this result

```
with at_css example:


with css
C27.11 
C27.11 Manufacture of electric motors, generators and transformers
C27.33 
C27.33 Manufacture of wiring devices
```

So, as you can see, using `.css` instead of `.at_css` will solve your issue.

Using `.at_css('.businesscategory').children` will yield whitespace nodes, so be careful

```
puts "\n\nwith at_css().children"
doc.css("tbody tr").each do |company|
  company.at_css(".businesscategory").children.each do |category|
    puts category.text.inspect
  end
end
```

prints

```
with at_css().children
"\n      "
"C27.11 Manufacture of electric motors, generators and transformers"
"\n      "
"C27.33 Manufacture of wiring devices"
"\n    "
```

Comment: doesn't help... tried it aswell, but company.at_css(".businesscategory").children did it...

Comment: Be careful, `.children` will return all children, even ones that aren't elements, including text nodes for whitespace.